# Generate static typing of Column name in yii active record

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a yii basic app where test is database table **id,name**

and models

```
class Test extends ActiveRecord
{

    //public $name;
    //public $id;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{test}}';
    }
}
```

when i declare a $name/$id field in Test class.It not binding to database column name??

Is there any way to declare  **public $name;** and get the data/or set the data by static typing ?

Like a declare **public $name;** and in controller

```
    $test=new Test();

    $test->name='test2';
    $test->save(); //not working
```

Comment: its should work, What do you mean by not working?

Comment: if you uncomment //public $name; this line not working !!!!

Comment: Is name and id are table column fileds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must not** declare properties of ActiveRecord class of the same name as mapped database columns.

Mapped properties are fetched automatically and you have got access to them using standard getters and setters.

If you declare property like in your example property values are not fetched from database.

Comment: then how to make my column `name` static type ?

Comment: All mapped DB columns are public properties casted to proper type based on DB schema. What would you like to achieve? Maybe I can help.

Comment: by generating compiler suggestion with . .Say i declare test object t.so t->name ="set data" ? and name is fixed and readable code in model

Comment: If you are looking for typing hint you can declare phpDoc `@property <type> $name` in class description, all good IDEs can read these. As for the setting mapped property like `$obj->name = 'something'` - it should work properly.